# Marking and assembly as required to be distributed

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild

I am developing a custom framework assembly that holds the business logic for one of my clients. This assembly is referenced pretty much anywhere from WinForms to ASP.Net etc.

A few weeks ago I decided to add ( after PostSharp and IPWorks ) Newtonsoft.Json to get some serialized output of classes. Works like a charm.

Problem I am facing right now is that I cannot get the Newtonsoft.Json assembly to automatically copied into a project that references the framework. During compile of the Framework both PostSharp and IPWorks are correctly copied into the bin folder of whatever application uses the framework ( as reference ) but the Newtonsoft.Json assembly ... I cannot find a way to get that copied over.

I know this must be simple, but I have not found a way to make that happen. I have searched hi and low ( I know how to "Google it !" ) but came up with zilch ( VS2012 project file format, MSBuild documentation etc ).

In details:

MyFramework.dll

- nsoftware.IPWorks.dll
- PostSharp.dll
- Newtonsoft.Json

When compiling ... no problems

MyApplication.exe

- MyFramework.dll
- - nsoftware.IPWorks ( automatically included )
- - PostSharp ( automatically included )
- - Newtonsoft.Json ( MISSING all the time )

Which leads to me, obviously, forgetting that I have to copy the dll over manually.

I need a way to somehow tell MyFramework.dll that it's not only accompanied by IPWorks and PostSharp but also by Newtonsoft.Json without having to manually add it to MyApplication.exe

Answer (score 0):

On the reference properties have you set copy local as true?